# In NYS, can a medical marijuana patient be fired or denied a job for a positive drug test result for THC?

Tags: employment, new-york-state, new-york-city, medical-marijuana

In New York State, do medical marijuana patients have legal protections when it come to THC showing up in a drug test? Assuming they are both living and working within the state.

Additionally, do any localities such as New York City have differing rules?